# How to prove that a time-oriented spacetime possesses a nowhere vanishing timelike vector field?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, time, vector-fields

Penrose gave a very brief proof to this question. Since the spacetime is paracompact, there exists a positive definite metric called $h_{ab}$. Then, the nowhere vanishing time-like vector field $V^a$ is determined by the following equations:

$(g_{ab}-\lambda h_{ab})V^b=0$ with $\lambda>0$, and $h_{ab}V^aV^b=1$.

(By his convention, the signature of the Lorentzian metric is (+,-,-,-))

I totally cannot understand the logic. Although $g_{ab}V^aV^b=\lambda h_{ab}V^aV^b=\lambda>0$, so $V^a$ is indeed a time-like vector, how can we be sure there is such kind of vector field satisfying the conditions?

Comment: What is the definition of time oriented spacetime you are using?

Comment: The one used in Wald's book. The lightcone is defined within the tangent vector space.

Comment: As far as I remember Wald's book defines a time-orientable spacetime as a connected spacetime admitting a continuous timelike (thus non-vanishing) vector field. Therefore I cannot understand what your are trying to prove actually. If the spacetime is oriented, it is orientable as well and thus there is the required vector field by definition.

Comment: Hi, Moretti. Thanks for replying! I might not phrase my question in a correct way. What I try to ask is why the vector field given by Penrose is a nonvanishing, continuous timelike vector field. I already know it is timelike, but how to show that it is also continuous is not clear based on Penrose's construction. Hopefully, this will clear your puzzle.